# Is it possible to change the signal handlers in another process?

Tags: unix, signals

I found out the `nohup` tool today, and was wondering about it's implementation. Specifically,  it seems like there must be a way to tell another process, or a child process, to ignore certain signals. Is there a system call, or something like that, that does this?

Answer (score 2):

May the [source](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/nohup/nohup.c?view=markup) be with you :)

Disclamer: the phrase is actually not mine, but of [Marshall Kirk McKusick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Kirk_McKusick).

Comment: +1. That's essentially 2 lines of code if you remove all the additional processing. :)

Answer (score 2):

nohup simply `exec`'s the command you give it after ignoring the `HUP` signal.  From the source code:

```
signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
/* skipping some stuff ... */
execvp (*cmd, cmd);
```

I'm assuming this means that if the specified command did something like:

```
signal (SIGHUP, SIG_DFL);  /* restore default HUP signal handler */
```

nohup wouldn't work properly.

Comment: There is a convention that programs should leave signals that were ignored on entry alone (and not set a handler or default action for them).

This convention is mainly necessary for nohup and non-job control background (&) processes which inherit SIGINT and SIGQUIT ignored. (With more modern facilities such as setsid() and job control (separate process groups), inheriting signals is not needed as the offending signals will not be sent at all.)

Comment: Ah, that seems like a sensible convention.  I couldn't imagine why anyone would want to reset HUP to default, but I thought I would point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Process preserves signal mask after exec call.

See sources for nohup here, for example:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-118/nohup/nohup.c

For the details on exec() call see here:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html

Namely:

> The new process shall inherit at least
>   the following attributes from the
>   calling process image:
>
> ... Process signal mask (see
>   sigprocmask())